# I have a dynamically generated date in html as {{@subcon.InsuranceExpiry}}. How do I pass this value to jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Passing dynamically generated date to jQuery

I can get the same thing working in vue.js but have to do it in jQuery and am stumped.

In my jquery this just displays the current date

```
var newdate1 = $('#formatteddate');
newdate1 = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
console.info(newdate1);

This is my html
<div class="eight wide column" id="formatteddate">
Insurance expiry: {{@subcon.InsuranceExpiry}}
</div>

No error but it's not passing the intended date to jQuery.
```

Comment: `$('#formatteddate').val()` !? Check it out...

Comment: Thanks heaps I've tried that previously but I'm still getting the current date in the console.

var newdate1 = $('#formatteddate').val();
newdate1 = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
console.info(newdate1);

Comment: `$('#formatteddate').text()` Will show you something like _"Insurance expiry: 09/07/2019"_

Comment: Thanks again it's still writing out the current date in the console and the date is still being rendered on the page in yyyy-mm-dd format like 
_Insurance expiry: 2019-12-31_

Comment: Maybe the function `moment()` calls the current date. What throws you this: `console.info($('#formatteddate').text());` ?

Comment: great that throws a rendered date in the console which appears like _2019-12-31_, just need to work out how to change the format to dd/mm/yyyy which is what I was intending to use moment for

Comment: Lol, try this then: `var dd = $('#formatteddate').text(); dd = 'Insurance expiry: ' + dd.replace('Insurance expiry: ','').substring(8) + '/' +  dd.replace('Insurance expiry: ','').substring(5,7)+ '/' + dd.replace('Insurance expiry: ','').substring(0,4);console.info(dd);`

Comment: Awesome! in the console it's writing out _Insurance expiry: 25/09/2019_ which is correct but sorry for simple question can't work out how to now write out this value on the page?

Comment: I can get the first instance of the date reformatted but reformatting is not being applied to remaining one by iterating see code below so I'll keep on it! Thanks for all your help JC Hernández.  

    var sum = 0;
    var dd = $('#formatteddate').text();
    dd = dd.substring(8) + '/' + dd.substring(5,7)+ '/' + dd.substring(0,4);
    for ( var i = 0; i < dd.length; i++ ) {
    sum += dd[i];
    $("#formatteddate").html(dd);
    };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres your own answer @Richard ;)

```
var sum = 0; var dd = $('#formatteddate').text(); 
dd = dd.substring(8) + '/' + dd.substring(5,7)+ '/' + dd.substring(0,4); 
for ( var i = 0; i < dd.length; i++ ) { 
  sum += dd[i]; $("#formatteddate").html(dd); 
};
```